# Automatically update Twitter status

Tags: javascript, web-services, twitter

I want to update my Twitter status when a new post about java is inserted in stack overflow, is there any web service I can use on Stack overflow website in order to do that ?

Comment: can you tell me at least why your down voting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Exchange exposes an API that can be used to retrieve site information.  The documentation for the APIs can be found here: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs